# Can't integrate Firebase with my application

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When I integrate Firebase with my app, Build failed with an exception.

Although the first error that occurred was a gradle update, i've tried and i still get an error while running gradle.

Because there was no error in the code and the amount of coding was too much, I can only show error messages.

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\82109\AndroidStudioProjects\instargram_clon\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
  Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>            *********************************************************
>   WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
>            See goo.gl/CP92wY for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
>            This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
>            *********************************************************
>     Command: C:\Users\82109\AndroidStudioProjects\instargram_clon\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

※ When integrating Firebase with my app, I'm wondering if several versions are all up-to-date. This is because i have optionally and randomly changed to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for firebase you can integrate your app manually see [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#console)
for a quick answer follow this steps:**android**

1. Create a Firebase project
2. Register your app with Firebase
3. Add a Firebase configuration file (google-services.json)
4. Add Firebase SDKs to your app

WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX => update your image_picker